# Fermat's method to compute the perimeter of $x^3 = ay^2$

Tags: analytic-geometry, math-history, curves

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Wallis), the problem of finding the perimeter of the curve $x^3 = ay^2$ was solved by Wallis and also by Fermat in 1660 by a different method. I'm interested in finding about the method of Fermat and am looking for some reference(s) regarding it.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the *Historical Methods* section on this page.In this article Fermat's method is illustrated for the curve $y^2=x^3$.
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length

There is also a reference to a paper published by Fermat.(It's not in English).
[Geometric dissertation on curved lines in comparison with straight lines](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length#cite_note-7)